# Why is there a long "busy" time when drawing gridlayout in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am developing an app in app designer (MATLAB r2020b) where I want to have a dashboard-like tableoverview with 40-60 rows and 16 columns. For this I am using gridlayout because I need:

- multilines in some cells
- Images in some cells

It only takes about 3-4 seconds to run the code and prepare the gridlayout, but MATLAB keeps "busy" for additional 20-40 seconds. How can this be and is there anything I can do to optimize speed performance?
I am doing this in app designer and want to show the grid in a panel. However, I have written some dummy data below as an example for creating the grid in a figure, by running the script.

```
clear
%%PREPARE DUMMY DATA
    NoOfRows =  60;
    testData= cell(NoOfRows,16);
    
    for h = 1:16
        testData(:,h) =  cellstr(char(randi([65 80],NoOfRows,1)));
    end
    
    testData = cell2table(testData);   
    testData.Properties.VariableNames = {'Navn','blabla','F','Team','I/S','Veg','Fisk','RF','Mandag','Tirsdag','Onsdag','Torsdag','Fredag','Bemærkninger','Møder','Start/slut'};
%%PREPARE GRID LAYOUT
    BottonFontColor = [0 0 1];
    CellColor = [0.2 0.4 0.6];
    FullHeaderColor = [0 0 0.5];
    
    
    TestColor1 = [0.1 0.1 0.1];
    TestColor2 = [0.6 0.6 0.6];
    TestColor3 = [1 1 1];
    TestColor4 = [0.4 0.4 0.4];
    TestColor5 = [0.5 0.5 0.5];
    TestColor6 = [0.6 0.6 0.6];
    TestColor7 = [0.7 0.7 0.7];
    TestColor8 = [0.8 0.8 0.8];
    TestColor9 = [0.9 0.9 0.9];
    TestColor10 = [0.1 0.1 1.0];
    
    %Create gridlayout
    fig = uifigure('Position',[100 100 440 320]);
    grid = uigridlayout(fig,[height(testData) 16],'Scrollable','on');
    grid.Visible = 'off';
    
    %Set grid properties 
    grid.ColumnSpacing = 0;
    grid.RowSpacing = 0;
    RowHeight = cell(1,height(testData));
    RowHeight(:) = {90};
    RowHeight(1) = {45};
    grid.RowHeight = RowHeight;
    grid.ColumnWidth = {100,25,100,35,35,35,35,'1x','1x','1x','1x','1x',230,110,65,50};
        
    %Vectorize Data table
    test = table2cell(testData);
    test = test';
    test = test(:);    
    
    %create a table row indicator correlated to the original table dimensions
    row = 0;
    %loop over every cell in the vectorized table (cellarray)
    for i = 1:height(testData)*16
        % returns the remainder after division of i by 16
        n = mod(i,16);
        switch n
            case 1 %Name
                row = row+1;
                if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                else
                    uit = uibutton(grid,'Text','Test1');
                    uit.FontColor = BottonFontColor;
                end
            case 2 %Fase
                uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                if row == 1
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                else
                    uit.BackgroundColor = CellColor;
                end
            case 3 %Team
                uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",12,'Editable','on');
                if row == 1
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                else
                    uit.BackgroundColor = CellColor;
                end                    
            case 4 %I/S (icecream / snickers)
                 if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                 else
                     uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', "",'Editable','on');
                     uit.BackgroundColor = CellColor;
                 end
            case 5 %Veg
                 if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                 else
                     uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', "",'Editable','on');
                     uit.BackgroundColor = CellColor;
                 end
            case 6 %Fish
                if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                else
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', "",'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = CellColor;
                end
            case 7 %Refeed
                uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                if row == 1
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                else
                    uit.BackgroundColor = CellColor;
                end                 
            case 8 %Mandag
                 if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",16,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor1;
                 else
                     uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                     uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor2;
                 end
            case 9 %Tirsdag
                 if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",16,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor3;
                 else
                     uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                     uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor4;
                 end
            case 10 %Onsdag
                 if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",16,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor5;
                 else
                     uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                     uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor6;
                 end
            case 11 %Torsdag
                 if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",16,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor7;
                 else
                     uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                     uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor8;
                 end
            case 12 %Fredag
                 if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",16,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor9;
                 else
                     uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                     uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor10;
                 end
            case 13 %Bemærkninger
                uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",12,'Editable','on');
                if row == 1
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                else
                    uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor1;
                end
            case 14 %Statusmøde
                uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",12,'Editable','on');
                if row == 1
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                else
                    uit.BackgroundColor = CellColor;
                end
            case 15 %Vægt
                if row == 1
                    uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', "Vægt","FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                else 
                    uit = uibutton(grid,'Text',{'Blabla'});
                    uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor5;
                end
            case 0 %StartSlutDato
                uit = uitextarea(grid,'Value', test{i},"FontSize",14,'Editable','on');
                if row == 1
                    uit.BackgroundColor = FullHeaderColor;
                else
                    uit.BackgroundColor = TestColor6;
                end
        end
        
    end
    %Finalize gridlayout properties
    grid.Visible = 'on';
```